# Are there any mini games like TBoGT "Drug Wars" in Grand Theft Auto V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Are there any casual randomly generated crime mini-games similar to TBoGT "Drug Wars" that can be played at any time in GTA V?

All I've come across so far are story missions, side missions, and the random/ timed encounters like the security van near the Mt Chiliad gondola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting the closest I've come to the "random crime mini-game" is on GTA V Online. This delivers a seemingly endless stream of random crime missions which can (mostly) be played solo if desired.

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire video about the mini games and new activities [here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kf1VWd0DtFM)

These Mini games include:

- Golfing
- Stunt Plane Trials
- Tennis
- Liquor and ATM robberies
- Random World Events

The full list of 30 is in the video.